# Launching jupyter notebook from terminal starts signal desktop messenger as well

Tags: terminal, jupyter-notebook, signals, ubuntu-18.04

when I am launching a jupyter notebook from the terminal on my ubuntu 18.04, the signal desktop messenger app launches as well. Does anyone encountered this issue and knows how to solve it? Thanks

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I have the same issue here (Ubuntu 18.04) and I discovered that the default application to run *.html-Files was also changed to Signal Desktop App. After changing the default application for *.html backwards to Firefox jupyter notebook launches already in the browser.

Comment: Hi, thanks a lot for the answer! It was indeed the case for me as well. Honestly speaking I would have never thought about signal setting itself under the hood as the default *.html application.

Answer (score 4):

I've found a way to do this that is (possibly) more directly related to Jupyter. You can create a Jupyter config file and change the browser preference to whatever you like. Type:

`jupyter notebook --generate-config`

on the command line. It will tell you where the config file was created (probably `$HOME/.jupyter/jupyter_notebook_config.py`). Open the config file and look for the following line:

`#c.NotebookApp.browser = ''`

you can uncomment it and change it to include your desired web browser. For example this is how I changed it to firefox:

`c.NotebookApp.browser = '/usr/lib/firefox/firefox'`

Save the file, exit and try again.

This worked for me on Ubuntu 16.04.6 (LTS) and I had a similar problem but [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58180711/launching-jupyter-notebook-from-terminal-starts-signal-desktop-messenger-as-well/58225284#58225284) didn't work for me. The situation I found myself in was that jupyter launched Firefox correctly in a normal environment but it launched the wrong application when I was in a directory that used a different python version which was being controlled via `pyenv`. I was launching the notebook like this: `pipenv run jupyter lab`. For completeness it was launching Signal for me too and - no - I don't really understand why. I found help in the thread connected to [this issue](https://github.com/jupyter/notebook/issues/4304) on the jupyter/notebook Github page.

Comment: This is the actual answer!